# Control Inner iframe's from parent

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

According to this answer:

[Invoking JavaScript code in an iframe from the parent page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251420/invoking-javascript-in-iframe-from-parent-page)

I have an iframe that loads a page that has a div with the id `flash_container`

```
<iframe src="http://www.remote.com/a.html" id="iframeID">
```

I placed this code on my parent page (the page that loads the iframe) but it doesn't seem to work:

```
document.getElementById('iframeID').contentWindow.targetFunction();
function targetFunction() {
    var el = document.getElementById('flash_container');
    el.style.zoom = 0.7;
    el.style.MozTransform = 'scale(0.7)';
    el.style.WebkitTransform = 'scale(0.7)';
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to zoom-out the inner page inside the iframe from the parent page.

Comment: Where is the `targetFunction()` located? According to the answer you mention, it should be inside the content of the iframe.

Comment: No.. it's in the parent, not the iframe. According to the answer that's where it should be.. Am I wrong?

Comment: And what exactly is the problem?

Comment: @Jose Faeti - not zooming out..

Comment: but is the targetFunction() being called? could you please add something inside it to check if it is being called? like alert('hello!'), or some debug log?

Comment: @Or: Quote from the question you refer to: "Please note that my problem is not changing the source url of the iframe, but invoking function defined in the iframe."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible to say for certain what's wrong, but I have some ideas you might want to look into.

1. Make sure that the iframe is loaded. Trying to do something inside a frame that hasn't finished loading clearly won't work
2. Are you sure that you don't have cross-domain problems. You cannot manipulate the contents of a cross-domain iframe.

Comment: Probably no. 2, It's not in the same domain. Nothing I can do?

Comment: Sadly (luckily for the average user, actually), theres nothing you can do about it with javascript. You could proxy the request via your own web server that pulls the site using PHP etc and then prints it out on the same domain. This would enable iframe embedding of sites on other domains. This, however, causes other problems, for example if the target site tries to use AJAX, it would generate a cross-domain error and fail.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you could, if both side (your page and the page in the iframe) agree on sharing information, you could use message passsing. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/7938270/1571709